operation did not complete successfully
program not excuting
i tried running the program but i am getting come kind of error which i am not getting.
the program is:-
    #include<stdio.h>
    int main(){
        int n;
        printf("how many times u want to print");
        scanf("%d",&n);
        for (int i=1;i<=n;i=i+1){
        printf("i miss you ini \n");
        }
        return 0;

    }

error i am getting:-
rogram 'a.exe' failed to run: Operation did not complete successfully because the file contains a virus or potentially unwanted softwareAt line:1 char:1

.\a.exe




At line:1 char:1

.\a.exe

  + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (:) [], ApplicationFailedException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandFailed




That sound like your virus scanner is interfering with the execution of your program. If the virus scanner reports that the file you just created is the only file that is infected on your computer, then it is probably a false positive. In that case, you may want to consider temporarily disabling the virus scanner or adding the directory in which your program resides to the exception list of your virus scanner, to see if this fixes the problem.

I exclude the folder tree where I compile code, from the AV.

Try modifying your program with some extra lines of code (not comments), which will change the signature. It's not guaranteed but can sometines work.

Completely unrelated to your issue, but a good habit to get into is checking the return value of scanf to ensure it succeeded. Otherwise n could be uninitialized and you could enter the dreaded realm of undefined behavior.

@Chris what do mean by, "dreaded realm of undefined behavior''

It's said, that some solutions may return from that realm, but even the best algorithms may crumble to dust. Please see Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior.
